# Finding a text in Word and insert data after it

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have following VBA script to copy data from Excel worksheets to Word. This works fine.

Now before pasting I want to search the name of the sheet in the Word document and paste its respective data below it. So far I have included the find function in my script but not sure how to carry on further.

How do I get the location of found text and make the paste insert after it?

```
Sub ETW()
    
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Dim WordTable As Word.Table
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim pasteRange As Word.Range
    Dim StartCell As Range
    Set StartCell = Range("A2")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True
    WordApp.Activate
    
    Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("D:\asd.docx")
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Debug.Print ws.Name, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        'ws.UsedRange
        LastRow = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        LastColumn = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
        ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Copy
        
        Debug.Print "LastRow: "; LastRow, "LastColumn: "; LastColumn
        
        'Columns("E:E").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        'Range("E2").Value = "Mandatory"
        
        With myDoc.Content.Find
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Text = ws.Name
            .Execute
        End With
        
        Set pasteRange = myDoc.Content
        pasteRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        pasteRange.Paste
        
'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
        'Set WordTable = myDoc.Tables(1)
        'WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
        myDoc.Save
        
EndRoutine:
'Optimize Code
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        
'Clear The Clipboard
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: This is more word-vba than excel-vba. You should make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which would be in word-vba and tag it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim findRange As Word.Range
'...
Set findRange = myDoc.Content
With findRange.Find
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Text = ws.Name
    .Execute
End With
'now findrange is the first match of the search text so we can paste behind
findRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
findRange.Paste
```

Of course you might want to insert something like a new line before pasting, e.g.

```
'...
findRange.InsertAfter vbCR
findRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
findRange.Paste
```